# No plugins are working in Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova

I can successfully install all plugins but none of them seems to work.

I have also the cordova.js included:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/tocca.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
```

Then when I use simple `$('.curpos').html(device.cordova);` in index.js, it does not work.

This is output from `cordova plugin` command:

```
com.admob.pro 2.6.2 "AdMob Plugin Pro"
com.google.playservices 19.0.0 "Google Play Services for Android"
com.rjfun.cordova.extension 1.1.4 "Cordova Plugin Extension"
org.apache.cordova.device 0.3.0 "Device"
```

Can anybody point to solution?

Edit:

This is my index.js

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady(), false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log(window.cordova);
    viewport = {
        width: $(window).width(),
        height: $(window).height()
    };
    // reklamy

    var ad_units = {
        android: {
            banner: ''
        }
    };

    var admobid = ad_units.android;
//      if (AdMob) {
//          AdMob.createBanner({
//              adId: admobid.banner,
//              position: AdMob.AD_POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
//              autoShow: true
//          });
//      }
    console.log(window.cordova);
    $('.curpos').html(device.cordova);

    $('.hello').html("<span style='color:green;'>Loaded!</span>");
    var doc = document.createElement("div");
    $(doc).html("Šířka: " + viewport.width + "<br>Výška: " + viewport.height);
    $('body').append("<div class='curpos'></div>");
    $('body').append(doc);
    $('body').append("<div style='position: absolute; z-index:-1; left: 0; top: 0; width: " + viewport.width + "px; height: " + viewport.height + "px; background: red;'></div>");
    $('body').on("tap", function (e, data) {
        var x = data.x;
        var y = data.y;
        $('.curpos').html("X: " + x + "<br>Y: " + y);
    });
}
```

Stringified version of window.cordova:

```
{"version":"3.7.1","platformVersion":"3.7.1","platformId":"android","callbackId":879098886,"callbacks":{},"callbackStatus":{"NO_RESULT":0,"OK":1,"CLASS_NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION":2,"ILLEGAL_ACCESS_EXCEPTION":3,"INSTANTIATION_EXCEPTION":4,"MALFORMED_URL_EXCEPTION":5,"IO_EXCEPTION":6,"INVALID_ACTION":7,"JSON_EXCEPTION":8,"ERROR":9}}
```

Comment: How are you debugging the project? Can you use Chrome dev tools to see the javascript console and look for errors? If you are using it, try typing `window.plugins` to see if that exists.

Comment: are you waiting for ``deviceReady`` event?

Comment: I use logcat it writes uncaught exception for device. I will check.

Comment: Yes, waitign for deviceready.

Comment: window.plugins is undefined

Comment: could you check if "cordova.js" is loaded? maybe there's the problem.

Comment: ``window.cordova`` what does it return?

Comment: It returns that it's an object

Comment: latest version of ``device`` is 1.0.0, also renamed as ``cordova-plugin-device``. What version of cordova do you use? Create a sample app and see if it's all good and then compare with your app to see the differences and identifiy the issue. Without more details/code, I cannot give you more possible solutions. Also, you could post the contents of ``JSON.stringify(window.cordova)``

Comment: With sample app it is working and I cannot seem to find why. My Cordova version is 4.3.0. I updated my question with index.js

Comment: Updated my question with the stringified version of window.cordova

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a sample app with your configuration and had the same issue, but I found out that you were missing something (comparing to a cordova app of mine).

HTML - add `onload` attribute on body tag:

```
<body onload="onLoad()">
```

..and in your `index.js` file - wrap `deviceready` listener inside `onLoad` fn:

```
function onLoad(){
   document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady(), false);
}
```

That should work! :)

*Normally, it should work without this, but for some reason it doesn't. I guess it has something to do with cordova/android/plugin version.*

Comment: I started my app with phonegap3.x and from then I had the ``onload`` event there (probably I was experiencing same issue). That app is using now the latest cordova/android/plugin versions and I just removed the ``onload`` event and it still works. So, yeah, probably there's a bug in older versions.